# How much electricity and time would mining a bitcoin consume right now?

Tags: mining-profitability, energy-consumption

I live in an area where electricity is really cheap, I'm talking 0.003 USD per kilowatts/hour. I've searched myself around internet apparently it takes 15 000 kilowatts/hour of power to mine a bitcoin, however that information I believe is outdated since hashes have significantly increased from last year and especially since last two weeks, so if someone could do the math I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of kilowatts needed to mine a bitcoin depend on the hashing your setting(rigs) can produce, so 15 000 kilowatts/hour of power is not a good metric

There is plenty of website that allow you to calcul if it can be profitable to mine bitcoin, based on your settings of 0.003 USD per kilowatts/hour yes it is

https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/btc?HashingPower=40&HashingUnit=TH%2Fs&PowerConsumption=1500&CostPerkWh=0.003&MiningPoolFee=1